# Clausula DELETE en MySQL me devuelve 0 row affected

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, delete

Tengo la siguiente tabla "contactos" de la cual quiero borrar un registro.

[image: Tabla Mysql Workbench]

En Workbench hago la siguente sentencia SQL

```
delete from contactos where nombre="Zapatero";
```

No borra el registro pero hace la consulta: devuelve 0 row affected

> 11:42:37   delete from contactos where nombre="Zapatero"   0 row(s) affected   0.000 sec

***¿Porqué no lo borra?*** ya había trabajado ejercicios con BBDD y nunca he tenido este problema.
Ya he desactivado el safe Updates.

Comment: Estas seguro que el nombre de la tabla la has escrito correctamente, prueba a realizar un ``show tables`` en el terminal de MySQL para ver tus tablas

Comment: ¿Te has fijado si hay algún espacio o algo así después de la palabra? Por ejemplo 'Zapatero '.
Si es así (o incluso para hacerlo más general) podrías poner `DELETE FROM contactos WHERE TRIM(nombre)="Zapatero";`
Revisa los espacios por si acaso y nos cuentas

Comment: La consulta que acepta es:                                                                                    
      DELETE FROM `agenda`.`contactos` WHERE (`nombre` = 'Zapatero');

Comment: Entonces Jose L. ... está resuelta la pregunta?

Comment: Debería funcionar indistintamente, con comillas dobles o simples, a no ser que en el contexto (PHP por ejemplo) estés creando una consulta con sintaxis errónea... Dinos si usas PHP u otro contexto. Y dinos ¿qué muestra esta consulta: **`SELECT LENGTH(nombre) AS size FROM contactos WHERE nombre LIKE '%Zapatero%';`**

Comment: Aunque es cierto que **la práctica habitual es usar comillas simples para los datos alfanuméricos** tanto en INSERT o UPDATE como en los criterios. Ya en el pasado Workbench [tuvo algún bug al respecto](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85115), no sé si sea tu caso.

Comment: La verdad es que poniendo la consulta como he mostrado con la condición WHERE entre paréntesis si que ha funcionado. No se si ha cambiado algo pero hace unos meses practicando consultas con otro schema no me hacía falta esto. De hecho, cuando borro el registro sin sentencia, sino dando click derecho y borrar fila, el mismo workbench genera esta sentencia con paréntesis en la condición así que es como lo he utilizado.

Comment: Dice como te ha comentado @VFG es la solución? Escribe como lo has solucionado en respuesta para que se resuelva

Comment: Si si, correcto. No había visto el comentatio. Disculpas. Al modificar la sentencia así funciona

Comment: Entonces es que tenias algún espacio... @VFG pon tu respuesta

Comment: No no, espacio creo q no. Lo estube comprobando. Al poner la condición WHERE entre paréntesis es cuando funcionó